# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is only pointing to a line

Tags: java, arrays, regex, exception

I keep getting an exception in my program of java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at RegexReverseWords.reverseWords (line 23) and at RegexReverseWords.main (line 7). I am not sure what is causing this exception to happen. I am missing something on this for this to work properly?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexReverseWords{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverseWords("Hello, world! How are you?"));
        System.out.println(reverseWords("ABCDEFG! HIJKLMNOP? QRSTUV: WZ; YZ..."));
        System.out.println(reverseWords("!!! sTRIng ... Break... ???!!!...,, hmmm"));
    }

    public static String reverseWords(String input) {
        final String PUNCTUATIONS = ",!?:;,";
        final String MATCHER_REGEX = "[^" + PUNCTUATIONS + "]+";
        final String SPLIT_REGEX = "[" + PUNCTUATIONS + "]+";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(MATCHER_REGEX).matcher(input);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String[] words = input.split(SPLIT_REGEX);

        int wordIndex = words.length - 1;

        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, words[wordIndex]);
            wordIndex++;
        }

        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();

    }
}
```

Comment: `int wordIndex = words.length - 1;` - `matcher.appendReplacement(sb, words[wordIndex]);` - `wordIndex++;`. At the second iteration, `wordIndex == words.length`.

Comment: So the first time through that while loop, `wordIndex` is pointing to the last word in the list.  What do you think happens after `wordIndex++` if the loop runs a second time?

Comment: Array words has length of 3 with index (0,1,2) however when wordIndex = 3 so actually it is trying to fetch the 4th index because indexing starts with 0 as I stated above, hence ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is coming and its expected and true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > solution, you were not validating size, so the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
int wordIndex = words.length - 1;

while (matcher.find()) {
    if (words.length > wordIndex) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, words[wordIndex]);
        wordIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding in the if statement helped clear up the problem. I apperciate everyone who has commented on my problem.